# Classical music played by Atkinson Carillon at 24 Old Bond Street, London?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Can anyone identify the piece of classical music played by the Atkinson Carillon at 24 Old Bond Street, London?

Here are some links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajCptdmDk5g
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z0pRxA1dG8

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to distinguish through the jangling of the bells, but I think this is J.S. Bach's famous Cantata 208, ['Sheep May Safely Graze'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIUCRXMM4pE).  The easiest part to identify is the part where it speeds up with the repeated figure.